# JUnit test a static void method

Tags: java, string, logging, junit, void

So I created a log function so I can see the date of every action. I now want to unittest them. Because the function uses a void, I can't test the output.

I might change the void to a String, but then the point of using it as a void would be gone!

What are my options?

```
public class Logger {

    public static void log(String s) {
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft =
                 new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd '-' hh:mm:ss");
        System.out.println("[" + ft.format(d) + "]: " + s);
    }

}
```

JUnit

```
@Test
public void testLoggerEmptyString() {
    String s = "";
    log(s);
}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to test the side effects of your method. In this case, the side effect you want to observe is something getting written to `System.out`. You can use [`System.setOut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) to install your own `OutputStream`. From there you can verify that something was written to it.

For instance:

```
String s = "your message";
ByteArrayOutputStream sink = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
System.setOut(new PrintStream(sink, true));
log(s);
assertThat(new String(sink.toByteArray()), containsString(s));
```

Comment: Just remember to set System.out back after you're done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the library [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules). It automatically sets the `System.out` back after the test.

```
public void MyTest {
  @Rule
  public final StandardOutputStreamLog log = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

  @Test
  public void testLoggerEmptyString() {
    log("hello world");
    assertEquals("hello world", log.getLog());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I might change the void to a String, but then the point of using it as a void would be gone!

I don't think so. If your method would look like this:

```
public static String getLogMessage(String s) {
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd '-' hh:mm:ss");
    return String.format("[%s] %s", ft.format(d), s);
}
```

You could test the output and use it in your code with

```
System.out.println(Whatever.getLogMessage("Foo for the world"));
```

or even

```
System.err.println(Whatever.getLogMessage("Holy shit!"));
```